# Difference in closing reasons - move to superuser.com

Tags: support, close-reasons

What is the difference between

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

and

> belongs on superuser.com Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

closing reasons? How to decide which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Was that only recently added back in as a migration target perhaps? Not sure it is intentional but I guess the first one is useful for questions too old or crap to migrate but within the general computing hardware and software area.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The close reason *"belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"* is for questions that have the Stack Exchange quality standards (primarily showing research efforts and following the *How to Ask* guide of each site). If enough votes are cast, the Question is migrated automatically.

Questions of dubious quality should be voted as *"You may be able to get help on Super User"*. It gets closed at Stack Overflow, following its rules. And if the user happens to post the same question at Super User, it's up to *their users* to handle it.

I believe the mantra is **Don't migrate crap**.

Comment: **+1** for not migrating crap.

Comment: It should be noted that the OT reason also covers a wide range of topics that aren't crap but also aren't (currently) on-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange. The Super User link is just a suggestion (and links directly to the intro page).

Answer (score 6):

> belongs on superuser.com Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

This is your classic, been-around-for-years close reason. If enough people (four out of five) select this close reason, the question will be automatically migrated to Super User (or whichever site of the five on that pane is selected).

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

This is newer, introduced in a more recent of the handful of close-voting overhauls. Questions closed with this reason are *not* automatically migrated.

> How to decide which one is more appropriate?

If you're pretty sure that the question is appropriate for Super User (maybe you participate on that site, and you've picked up a feel), use the former. The question will be migrated automatically. If you're not sure, or the question isn't that great and you think it might be closed on Super User anyway, use the latter. No reason to ship questions around, get the OP's hopes up, just to dash them.

(Questions asked more than 60 days previous can't be migrated)